# Catch SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS

Tags: exception, try-catch, abap

I want to catch and handle `SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS` in my ABAP code.

I tried this:

```
  try. 
    SELECT *
      FROM (rtab_name) AS rtab
      WHERE (sub_condition)
      into table @<sub_result>
   .

  catch SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS into error.
    ...
  endtry.
```

But above code is not valid. I get this message:

> Type "SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS" is not valid

And I tried this:

```
  catch SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS = 123.
    SELECT *
      ...
    .
  endcatch.

  if sy-subrc = 123.
      ...
  endif.
```

But above code gives me:

> Instead of "SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS" expected "system-exception" (translated from german to english by me)

How to catch `SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS`?

This question is not about "why does this exception happen?". This is already solved. My code should handle the exception.

Comment: Are you using host variables (@...)? https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abenopensql_strict_mode_740_sp08.htm "If the content of a host variable read in an operand position needs to be converted to the target type, this is done using the rules for lossless assignments. If the assignment cannot be lossless, an exception is raised." It is not mentioned that the exception is "catchable", so I assume it is not.

Comment: SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS is no class Exception. You can find all SQL Exceptions here:https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenopensql_exceptions.htm

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai I updated the question: This question is not about "why does this exception happen?". This is already solved. My code should handle the exception.

Comment: @Dingermann you say "no class Exception". How to handle it?

Comment: @guettli sorry, it was clear, I just said it not possible to handle this exception the ususal way (i. e. with CATCH...). You have to change the SELECT statement, can you show as that code part?

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai I added the SQL. You said "you have to change the SELECT statement". What is your goal? V1: change sql to not raise the exception. V2: change sql make exception catchable?

Comment: @guettli you can not handle it. As JozsefSzikszai already said, you loose data when it is transferd to your INTO Variable. This can happen when the domain of your variable uses conversion routines. To be on the safe side, you can use the "new" OpenSQL Sysntax SELECT SINGLE XXX FROM YYY INTO @DATA(lv_xxx)...

Comment: @guettli Goal is V1, as V2 is not possible. Thanks for the code, but as this is dynamic, it does not help much. Have a look at this blog entry, might help to solve the issue: http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/sapsql_data_loss-abap-programming-error.aspx

Comment: @guettli this might give you an idea as well: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/10/08/abap-news-for-740-sp08-open-sql/ (see the comment of Jacques Nomssi and the answer from Horst Keller)

Comment: @guettli Dingermann has provided the link to the page of possible **exception classes** (CX_SY...) for Open SQL. Note: if an exception is not caught, it generates a **runtime error**. Anyway you may simply catch the root exception class (**`Catch CX_ROOT`**), so it will handle all possible catchable exceptions. Note: some exceptions can't be handled (there's no exception class) i.e. a runtime error occurs, and they are listed in the ABAP documentation (for instance, DBIF_RSQL_INVALID_REQUEST, ...) ; when a runtime error occurs, a **short dump** is generated (ST22).

Comment: @SandraRossi is right. Unfortunately you can't handle SQL exception SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS programmatically neither with catchable exception or system exceptions.

Since the issue is probably in the where statement (?), maybe the only thing you can do is to check one by one the length/type of right operands of the where condition with the table fields. Something like a string parsing of sub_condition variable, but personally I never did it before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS` is a runtime error.

As `SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS` is not a class-based exception, it is not possible to catch it using `try catch`.

As `SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS` is not a catchable **runtime error**, it is not possible to catch it using `try catch SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS`.

see the below catchable runtime errors.

https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenueb-abfb-sysexc.htm

Comment: The URL above links to the page "of the **obsolete** catchable runtime errors"

Comment: because  CATCH SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS is obsolete statement. i have never used it probably it was decades ago.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. How to handle a not catchable runtime error? Is there no way to handle it gracefully?

Comment: `Is there no way to handle it gracefully?` no. The only way is to convert host variables into proper datatype

Comment: @guettli there is no way to handle it. It is like you access a null reference which causes a short dump that you can’t catch. It is a flaw in the code and you have to fix it.

Comment: @Haojie thank you for this information. I will see how I can handle this (check the length of the input) myself.

Answer (score 6):

After some tries I can propose you a possible solution.

**This is a workaround:**

*I don't know if it can be applied to your case, since it needs the select statement to be wrapped into an RFC function module !*

The main point is that a short dump (message type X) CAN be handled in RFC calls.

So using an RFC (`CALL FUNCTION 'xxxxx' destination 'NONE'` for example) and using special exception `SYSTEM_FAILURE`, the system does not terminate the caller program, but instead it returns a `SY-SUBRC > 0` with the Short dump informations in  system message fields (SY-MSGxx).

**STEPS**

**Create a Function module (RFC enabled)** with your select statement input + the row type of the result table. (All parameters passed by value)

*You need this last parameter since generic tables can't be passed in RFC (no "TYPE ANY TABLE" allowed)*

```
FUNCTION Z_DYN_SEL .
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Local interface:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     VALUE(RTAB_NAME) TYPE  TABNAME16
*"     VALUE(SUB_CONDITION) TYPE  STRING
*"     VALUE(RESULT_TYPE) TYPE  STRING
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------

* RTAB_NAME: DB Table
* SUB_CONDITION: WHERE Condition
* RESULT_TYPE: The ROW type of the internal table

field-symbols <sub_result> type any table.

* DEFINE LOCAL DYNAMIC TABLE TO STORE THE RESULT
data: lr_res type ref to data.
create data lr_res type standard table of (result_type).
assign lr_res->* to <sub_result>.

* DYNAMIC SELECT
select *
  from (rtab_name) as rtab
 where (sub_condition)
  into table @<sub_result>.

* EXPORT RESULT TO A MEMORY ID, SO IT CAN BE RETRIEVED BY CALLER
export res = <sub_result> to memory id 'RES'.
```

**Main program:**
In this caller example some parameters are passed to the RFC.

KTOKD field (should be 4 chars long) is passed with a char10 value (producing your short dump).

If ANY Dump is triggered inside the function, we can now handle it.

If everything went fine, `IMPORT` result from the `EXPORT` statement inside the RFC

```
field-symbols <sub_result> type any table.
data: lr_res type ref to data.
create data lr_res type standard table of KNA1.
assign lr_res->* to <sub_result>.

data lv_msg type char255.

call function 'Z_DYN_SEL' destination 'NONE'
exporting
  rtab_name           = 'KNA1'
  sub_condition       = `KTOKD = 'D001xxxxxx'`
  result_type         = 'KNA1'
exceptions
  system_failure = 1 message lv_msg.

if sy-subrc = 0.
  import res = <sub_result> from memory id 'RES'.
else.
  write: / lv_msg.
  write : / sy-msgid, sy-msgno, sy-msgty, sy-msgv1, sy-msgv2, sy-msgv3, sy-msgv4.
endif.
```

**RESULTS**

After the RFC call in case of a short dump in the select statement, the program is not terminated and the following pieces of information are available

```
SY-SUBRC = 1
```

`lv_msg` is the error text (Data was lost while copying a value.)

```
Sy-msgid = 00
Sy-msgno = '341'
Sy-msgty = 'X'
Sy-msgv1 = 'SAPSQL_DATA_LOSS'
```